# How and where can I access old versions of autoinst?

Tags: autoinst, fontools

For a lot of packages, the developers mention a git repository or similar, where you can find the current and all older versions of it. However if this is not the case, what is the place to look?

Specifically I am looking for older versions of `autoinst.pl` which is located at https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/utilities/fontools/ on CTAN.

Comment: texlive svn? https://tug.org/texlive/svn/

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Texlive svn (and a git mirror) are available and go back many years, see  https://tug.org/texlive/svn and there is also a git mirror, where e.g. fontools can be found at https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/tree/trunk/texk/texlive/linked_scripts/fontools